# Django is_valid() throws ValueError when submitting a form. Not sure why

Tags: django, django-forms, validationerror

The following code creates a form based on a model, `Post`. Problem I am facing is that the form never validates and gives *ValueError* that *data did not validate* if I remove the `if post_form.is_valid():` check.

However, if I keep the code as shown below, that is, I keep the `if post_form.is_valid():` check, then it always fails and the `else` block is executed.

I was trying to save the User, which is a ForeignKey to Django's Auth, in my model and it turns out I cannot even get past this vlaidation error.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

```
#----------------------------Model-------------------------------------- 
class Post (models.Model): 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=1000, help_text="required, name of the post") 
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=False, help_text="user this post belongs to") 

    def __unicode__(self): 
        return self.name 

class PostForm(ModelForm): 
    class Meta: 
            model = Post 
#----------------------------./Model--------------------------------------

#----------------------------View-------------------------------------- 
@login_required 
def create_post (request): 
    if request.method == 'POST': 
        post_form = PostForm(request.POST) 
        if post_form.is_valid(): 
            post.save() 
            return render_to_response('home.html') 
        else: 
            return HttpResponse('not working') 
    else: 
        post_form = PostForm() 
        return render_to_response('create.html', {'post_form':post_form }) 
#----------------------------./View--------------------------------------

#----------------------------./Template--------------------------------------
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>home</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST" action='.'>{% csrf_token %}
    <p>{{post_form.name.label_tag}}</p>
    <p>{{post_form.name}}</p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Submit"/></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
#----------------------------./Template--------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your other post, you were trying to automatically insert the `user` field, which probably means you don't have a `user` field displayed in the template.

Exclude it if you plan to insert the user anyways.

```
class PostForm(ModelForm): 
    class Meta: 
            model = Post 
            exclude = ('user',) # exclude this

if request.method == 'POST': 
    post_form = PostForm(request.POST) 
    if post_form.is_valid(): 
        post = post.save(commit=False) 
        post.user = request.user
        post.save()  # now post has a user, and can actually be saved.
        return render_to_response('home.html')
```

Comment: Correct. I asked that question because I had no idea how to add User but later on I figured that my validation is failing. Thanks for remembering. I am new to this.

Comment: Ok, so as I thought, if you have a model with user field defined and non nullable, your form **has to** include the user field, or it has to be excluded and populated by other means (like the other examples I gave). The error message you are getting is "User: This field is required".

Comment: OMG. This is so cool. All I needed was the exclusion of the user field. And also, this takes works for the adding of the user automatically is I pass `user = request.user`. All this while, all I needed was this.

Answer (score 2):

It shows not valid, because the form is not valid. Presumably whoever submitted the form did not fill in the required fields. If you display the value of `form.errors` you will see why.

Alternatively, although we have to guess because you have not shown the template, you have not included all the required fields in the template itself, therefore the form will never be valid.

Remove the first `else` clause with its HttpResponse. The view will then default to showing the form again, complete with errors.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have added the template code also. It is a very small Model with only two fields, out which, one is a ForeignKey. I have deleted and recreated my DB also but I am not sure what is wrong with my code (or thinking, or implementation). Thanks.